# karma unit test runner directory injector error

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, karma-runner, test-runner

So in my app.module, i have some injectors that are actually directories that store html element directives for templates. The problem is that karma is complaining that the directories are not available. How do I load or get karma to ignore the injected dependencies?

Particular ones are: **templates**,**provider-form**,**checkout-form**

```
var app = angular.module("DoctiblePreTreatment", ['ngDialog', 'ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ui.select2', 'templates', 'provider-form', 'checkout-form', 'ui.mask', 'widget-filters', 'focus', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngGrid', 'google-maps', 'angularFileUpload', 'angularPayments', 'angular-loading-bar', 'ngAnimate', 'loader']);
```

error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module DoctiblePreTreatment due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module templates due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'templates' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

[image]

karma.conf.js file

```
  // Karma configuration
  module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
  // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
  basePath: '/Users/giowong/rails_project/doctible_pre_treatment/',

  // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
  frameworks: ['jasmine'],

  // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
  files: [
  'app/assets/components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/assets/components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/assets/components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'app/assets/components/ngDialog/js/ngDialog.js',
  'app/assets/components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'app/assets/components/jquery-1.11.1.min.js',
  'app/assets/javascripts/main.js',
  'app/assets/javascripts/**/**/*.js',
  'app/assets/javascripts/*.js',
  'spec/javascripts/*.js'
],

// list of files / patterns to exclude
exclude: ['app/assets/javascripts/angular-google-maps.min.js'



],

// web server port
port: 8080,

// level of logging
// possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,

// Start these browsers, currently available:
// - Chrome
// - ChromeCanary
// - Firefox
// - Opera
// - Safari (only Mac)
// - PhantomJS
// - IE (only Windows)
browsers: ['Chrome'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
singleRun: true
});
};
```

Comment: What is in your karma config file? It's possible that your forgot to include module JS file.

Comment: i just included my karma.conf.js, but the templates is not a actual module... its a diretory

Comment: Angular modules can't be directories(or I am missing something), are you sure that you don't have angular module called 'templates' somewhere? Second question - does this application work in browser environment (not karma)?

Comment: I checked everywhere, and i couldn't find a angular module named template. The application does work in the browser environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular dependencies are always modules, you can't be dependent on a folder. As such, if this is working in your browser, I would assume that you have build tools that are precompiling the html templates into javascript, and directly populating the `$templateCache` within modules (with the names that karma is looking for).

If this is the case, there is more than likely another javascript file being created that you need to make sure you have loaded into karma before your main app code (but after angular).

Check what scripts you are loading in your `index.html` file (you could look at the network or sources tabs of the chrome developer tools if you're having trouble finding it).